# How to make python read csv files and extract data and paste it another csv?

Tags: python, csv

Instead of using the output.csv If i want to have the category list words to be the file name.I tried but it ain't working.

```
import csv

handle_w = open('output.csv', 'wb')
csv_out = csv.writer(handle_w, delimiter=' ')

csv_out.writerow(["  ", "Waybill", "Contents", "  ", "Amount", "COD Amount", "Type", "  ", "Error"])

with open('ss.csv') as handle2:
    for each in handle2:
        j = each
        print j
        strng_conv = ''.join(map(str,j))
        file_name = strng_conv+'.csv'
        print file_name
        cat_file = open(file_name,'wb')
        cat_var =csv.writer(cat_file,delimiter=' ')


        with open('1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
            handle1 = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
            for row in handle1:
                if each.rstrip() in row:

                    cat_var.writerow(row)
        cat_file.close()
handle_w.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, first you need to read the two files. The second one `ss.csv` is very simple and I suggest to do not use `csv` library to read it.

Simply

```
import csv

def open_writer(tag):
    handle_w = open('%s.csv' %(tag, ), 'wb')
    return handle_w, csv.writer(handle_w, delimiter=' ')

handle0 = open('ss.csv', 'r')
writers = map(open_writer, [tag.rstrip() for tag in handle0])

handle0.close()

with open('ss.csv') as handle2:
    for w, tag in zip(writers, handle2):
        w[1].writerow(["  ", "Waybill", "Contents", "  ", "Amount", "COD Amount", "Type", "  ", "Error"])
        with open('1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
            handle1 = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
            for row in handle1:
                if tag.rstrip() in row:
                    w[1].writerow(row)

map(lambda w: w[0].close(), writers)
```

Comment: No,it is not a homework,its a task for analysis.It isn't working right

Comment: thanks,If iI want to create file and put them in it the matched content with the respected name ,how I will accomplish that?

Comment: you need to open a file in 'w' mode, initialize a cvs object, `handle_w` for exemple. Then write in the the file the header row, after instead of `print row` use `handle_w.writerow(row)`. at the end close the file.

Comment: can you help me with the exact code bcs still I am not able to get what I desire

Comment: I wrote the entire solution, changing the code upside.

Comment: What do you not understand? Try to find csv in python documentation. Ah, a last thing, it better use another delimiter, like ',' or '\t' or ';' for csv files.

Comment: check my edited code one last help plz,If i want my keywords to be the file name.how can I accomplish that,I have tried but it ain't working

Comment: Did, It's a bit more complicate, but I used some functional stuffs to don't use too much cycles. I hope it works

Comment: and how to print all the columns with their content instead of one?

Comment: to many questions, explain this and this other, but it all in the documentation. You need to RTFM. For the last question, what do you mean? it writes all column filtered in sub files.